# Mathematical Annotation in R

Tags: r, expression

In R, I can create text label "0 <= x" on my graph by saying

```
text(0, 0, expression(italic(0 <= x)));
```

Now, how can I create the label "0 <= x <= 1"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is a formal way, but try this:

```
plot(0,0,col=0)
text(0, 0, expression(italic(0 <= {x <= 1})))
```

Comment: Because "0 <= {x <= 1}" is a valid expression in R - its a bit like doing 0 <= (x <= 1), in that it evaluates x<=1 to get a true or false value, then evaluates 0 <= TRUE or 0 <= FALSE. Curly brackets instead create a block that doesn't show up in the rendered text, unlike round parentheses that would show up. Neat trick bro.

Comment: Here is another way to do this: `expression(italic(paste(0 <= x) <= 1))`, following Duncan Murdoch response on [Rhelp](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e9/help/10/01/2074.html).

Comment: @Spacedman yes, exactly. But I'm wondering why the `0 < 1 < 2` is invalid, while `0 + 1 + 2` is valid. In C, at least, it is not invalid (maybe undefined?). Actually the behavior of R would be preferable, since in/out types are not consistent in comparison ops (i.e., any -> logical), while math-ops are not (i.e., numeric -> numeric). But I could not find any documentation about this implementation. Do you know?

Comment: It's because mathematicians write expressions like "5 < x < 10" and expect them to be true if x is 6. However, computers evaluate TRUE and FALSE as 1 and 0. So "5 < x < 10" becomes "5 < (6<10)", which is "5 < TRUE" and then "5 < 1" and hence FALSE. 5 < x < 10 is FALSE if x=6. It's quite easy to modify R to do this - get the source, delete gram.c, change gram.y to give LT %left or %right precendence, recompile R. Sure enough 5 < 6 < 10 is now valid syntax, and FALSE. It would be much hassle to rewrite the language to convert 5 < x < 10 to 5 < x & x < 10. So you have to do it yourself.

Comment: @Spacedman thanks, I found that the comparison ops are defined as %nonassoc in gram.y. I meant I could not find any R document about his. So could you please tell me if you know the R official manual referring to this implementation.

Comment: Can't see it in the documentation from R-project.org, but often if questioned people will say 'read the source'. Suggest you post something to R-devel mailing list.